# Shifting elements in array by N elements

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array where each 'element' is composed of 4 consecutive values. Upon update I move the array by 4 values towards the end and insert 4 new values in the beginning.

Shift:

```
int m = 4;
for (int i = _vsize - 1; i + 1 - m != 0; i--){
     _varray[i] = std::move(_varray[i - m]);
}
```

Insertion:

```
memcpy(&_varray[0], glm::value_ptr(new_element), 4 * sizeof(float));
```

where `new_element` is of type `glm::vec4` containing said 4 new values.

Any suggestions on how to improve this?

(Right now Im only shifting by one element, but want the flexibility of being able to shift say 8 times, without having to put this in a loop)

Thank you.

Comment: `std::rotate` does something like this I think(I never used it, but it rotates range of elements inside container, including arrays)

Comment: What other operations do you need for this data structure? Using a reversed vector could be an idea. I.e. instead of inserting at the beginning, insert at the end. And when you want to iterate over it, do it in reverse order (with `rbegin()`, `rend()`)

Comment: Basically, these are points for a line. When my object moves Im 'discarding' the last point and add a new point after a specific time interval. 
Im hoping that there is a way to quickly shift the array onto itself in any direction (my array is interleaved, positions and color, both vec4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`std::copy_backward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward). You want to copy a range of values to another range in the same container. Since the ranges overlap *and you are copying to the right* you can't use regular `std::copy` but must use `std::copy_backward` instead.

```
int m = 4; // make this a multiple of your 'element' size
std::copy_backward(&_varray[0], &_varray[_vsize - m], &_varray[_vsize]);
```

There is also [`std::move_backward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move_backward) but that doesn't really matter since your `float` values aren't movable.

Comment: Tried this, dont know if im doing it right, did you mean as so:
     std::copy_backward(&_varray[0], &_varray[_vsize - 4*sizeof(float)], &_varray[_vsize]);
It reports that Im reading past the array size.
Oh and I actually have floats, I dont know why i wrote double, ill edit.

Comment: @mike: You don't need to do that `*sizeof(float)` scaling at all. When you use pointers as iterators (for example, `&_varray[0]`) the compiler knows the size of the pointed-to type and does the correct thing for you.

Comment: Removed that, still get the 'subscribt out of range'. Doing this: std::copy_backward(&_varray[0], &_varray[_vsize - 4], &_varray[_vsize]);

Comment: @mike: Is `_vsize` the number of elements in the array (not the number of bytes)? If so, `&_varray[_vsize]` should be a valid one-past-the-end iterator for the array. Show the declaration of `_varray`.

Comment: @mike: There is also some danger of computing an invalid index if `_vsize` is less than `m`.

Comment: Yes _vsize is the total number of values, the array is interleaved, first 4 position coord then 4 color values - this repeats. I wanted to keep it simple but in fact I want to shift the array by 8, I figure that should be the same thing: std::copy_backward(&_varray[0], &_varray[_vsize - 8], &_varray[_vsize]); - still getting vector out of range

Comment: @mike: I can't reproduce your problem. [Live demo at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/7Z37uw)

Comment: Blastfurnace's solution did work. I got it wrong at first as I had kept an improper size of my array from a previous debug.