# Remove element from array then shift other elements over

Tags: c++, arrays

This is my first question here and I'm excited to be part of the community.

I was motivated to post here by running into a severe problem with a remove function. I am trying to remove using index and count keywords I am trying to remove strips of elements from arrays. I drew out different scenarios on paper but found no discernible pattern so I have to ask here.

Let's say you have 
    `char array[] = {'A','B','C','D','E'};`
My function remove has this prototype
`void remove(char arr[], int& size, int element, int count)`

If one were to write, with size already declared, `remove(array, size, 2, 2)` then if printed the array must print ABE. The function must go to index 2, then remove two elements, then shift the others over.

Here is the function I tried to implement:

```
void remove(char arr[], int& size, int element, int count) {
for (int i = element;  i < count; i++) {
    arr[element] = arr[element + 1];
}
size = size - count; }
```

I could write the function to fit specific test cases but I cannot generalize it to work for all different inputs. I am fairly sure that the `size = size - count;` is correct as that consistently 'removes' the proper number of elements off the end, but I'm not 100% sure.

How can I implement this function correctly? I see others have asked similar questions, but not for removing potentially multiple elements at a time. I also have zero knowledge of vectors and I don't think using them would work for the rest of my program.

Comment: Just saw essentially the same question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26434416/103167

Comment: Oh I'm newer; nothing in that question looks familiar to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `std::rotate` in the following fashion:

```
void remove(char arr[], int& size, int element, int count) {
  std::rotate(arr + element, arr + element + count, arr + size);
  size = size - count;
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27622fef6a3d3e1e)

Edit:

Adding the requested checks:

```
void remove(char arr[], int& size, int element, int count) {
  if(element < size) {
    if(count + element > size) count = size - element;
    std::rotate(arr + element, arr + element + count, arr + size);
    size = size - count;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works just fine if count is in the right range but I'm running into the same problem I mentioned below. If count is bigger than size it should still be able to store values in the array (to be printed) if it starts at an index other than 0. So I have to figure out how to do that so this part implements perfectly.

Comment: I used an if/else to implement it perfectly. This worked but I needed to include algorithm too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a couple of simple changes, move the element count elements ahead to the current one with `arr[element] = arr[element + count];`. Also change the for loop to count up to `size - count`.

Comment: I tried this an it worked for a couple cases, including the ABE one I mentioned. However, if a count larger than the size is input, it erases every element. If `char arr[] = {'a','b','c'};` and `remove(arr, size, 2, 23);` is entered, the array should still be ab. Should I put an if/else in there to prevent it from erasing the whole thing? If so what would that look like?

Comment: just cap count to size - element at the beginning of the function.